# blog.example.com(example.com/blog) or another-domain.example

Tags: domains, blog

I have a website which is going to show my shareware, another site for my blog. I will post all my thinkings/development tips/design tips/business experience on my blog, but most of them are not related to my shareware. Software users may not interested in my blog. In this case, is it still better to host my blog to another domain?

Comment: I don't think this has strictly to do with programming. Anyway, I like it when a company has blog.example.com or example.com/blog. It's probably better also for SEO purposes.

Comment: i'd say "think branding" in this case. you will brand you url/domain with shareware and blog. is that good? if so, go ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on just how disjoint the blog posts are from the shareware I would create a new domain for the blog. Then I would use specific tags on posts about the shareware and use a tag RSS feed to put those posts into a news section on the shareware site. Doing this would give you the flexibility to have multiple sites pulling from your blog on different topics. If someone really wants to see all your posts they can click through to your blog from the other site.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - both, but the blog.domain.com should only list posts related to domain.com using domain.com design/layout (RSS feed solution sounds ok).

Answer (score 0):

I like Carson's approach. Both my product site and my blog site are created using wordpress, and the feeds are managed by feedburner. I searched the web and found feedburner may have [limited support for category](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/feedburner-rss-feeds-faq-problems-tips/1199/), but wordpress can support [feed for category](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) very well. So The solution can be:

- Create 2 feedburner feeds from my blog, one for all the posts of blog (feed1), and the other for one category specified for products (feed2).
- Feed1 will be set as my feed for blog
- Feed2 will be set as my feed for product site

Looks not too bad, the only concern is that subscribers may getting confused by 2 domains.

Edit: However, when I start to think more about branding. Host 2 domains have no contribution to brand, just confusion. So the answer should be clear, www.domain.com/blog is better. Better for SEO, rank, and less confusion to visitors. But we do can make 2 different feeds for different types of visitors.